# Extract first digit (in the middle of a string) in pivot_longer: names_pattern

Tags: r

Need to extract the first digit of the following phrases
drink_type_1_Day_7  and drink_vol_1_Day_7 the digits will vary between 1-10

This is to facilitate a pivot longer move. In the absence of *Day_7 I have used the expression (.*)*(.*) to achieve this. When I construct a regex expression and place it into names_pattern such as \d+

I get the following error: `regex` should define 2 groups; 1 found.

Is one approach to create a regex that forms 2 groups
Group 1 contains the first digit
Group 2 contains everything else ?

If so any advice would be much appreciated

````
library(tidyr)


study_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
drink_type_1_Day_7 <-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
drink_vol_1_Day_7 <- c(100,500,1000,100,500,750)
drink_type_2_Day_7 <-c(NA,3,2,1,NA,3)
drink_vol_2_Day_7 <- c(NA,125,300,200,NA,500)

drink_df  <- data.frame(study_id,drink_type_1_Day_7,drink_vol_1_Day_7,drink_type_2_Day_7,drink_vol_2_Day_7) 

drink_df <- drink_df %>% mutate_at(c('drink_type_1_Day_7','drink_type_2_Day_7'), as.factor) 

drink_df_pivot <- drink_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("drink"), 
               names_to = c(".value", "drink"),
               names_pattern = "         ") %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(study_id, drink_type) %>% 
  dplyr:: summarise(drink_vol = sum(na_if(drink_vol,0), na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% pivot_wider(names_from = drink_type, values_from = drink_vol, 
              names_prefix = "drink_vol_", values_fill = 0) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-contains("NA"))```
````

Comment: Can you show your expected long format?  Do you want `names_pattern =  "^([^0-9]+\\d+)_(.*)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could either create three columns from the substring or two columns by not capturing the inner digits (based on the summarisation step) in `pivot_longer` , by capturing the non-digit characters as first group (`([^0-9]+)`) followed by the `_`, capture the inner digits (`(\\d+)`), followed by `_` and capture the rest of the characters for the 'day' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
drink_df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("drink"),       
          names_to = c(".value", "digit", "day"),   
             names_pattern = "^([^0-9]+)_(\\d+)_(.*)",  
values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(study_id, drink_type) %>%
 summarise(drink_vol = sum(drink_vol, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  study_id drink_type drink_vol
     <dbl> <fct>          <dbl>
1        1 1                100
2        2 2                500
3        2 3                125
4        3 2                300
5        3 3               1000
6        4 1                300
7        5 2                500
8        6 3               1250
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `names_sep = '_\\d+_'`:

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)

drink_df %>%   
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("drink"),       
               names_to = c(".value", "digit"),    
               names_sep = '_\\d+_',
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(drink_vol = sum(drink_vol, na.rm = TRUE),.by = c(study_id, drink_type)) 

  study_id drink_type drink_vol
     <dbl> <fct>          <dbl>
1        1 1                100
2        2 2                500
3        2 3                125
4        3 3               1000
5        3 2                300
6        4 1                300
7        5 2                500
8        6 3               1250
```